# How to make the table adaptive?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is an [example](https://codepen.io/sochi-russia/pen/XvPaBN) number generator

Forms many combinations of 5 numbers + 1 number. I can’t adapt the table so that it is full-width for mobile (results in one line) and for PC (results in columns). The peculiarity is that the sixth number should be to the right of the previous five, like this `x-x-x-x-x x`

Here is the javascript itself forming the table when outputting data

```js
function generate() {
  document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML = "";
  const numbers = (new Array(36)).fill(1).map((a, i) => a + i);
  let resultSet = new Map();
  let qnt = parseInt(document.getElementById('quantity').value, 10);
  while (resultSet.size < qnt) {
    let nums = shuffle(numbers).slice(0, 5);
    let key = (nums.sort() + '');
    resultSet.set(key, nums);
  }
  resultSet.forEach(val => {
    const main = createTableWithContent(val.join('-'), "one");
    const additional = createTableWithContent(randInt(), "two");
    main.append(additional);
    document.getElementById("myTable").append(main);
  })
}

function shuffle(arr) {
  return arr.map(el => {
    return {
      item: el,
      sort: Math.random()
    }
  }).sort((a, b) => a.sort - b.sort).map(el => el.item);
}

function randInt(min = 1, max = 4) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function createTableWithContent(content, className) {
  const tableEl = document.createElement("TABLE");
  tableEl.className = className || "";
  tableEl.append(content);
  return tableEl;

}
```

```html
<input id="quantity" type="text" placeholder="Number of combinations" style="background: #ffffff!important;color: #8f2d00!important;font-size: 20px!important;" /><input class="annoying-btn" type="button" value="Get combinations" onclick="generate()" />
<div id="myTable"></div>
```

Please help me make the blocks mobile responsive form. Thanks in advance, with great respect

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks for answer. I can’t adapt the block version either

Comment: What is "adaptive"? Are you meaning mobile responsive?

Comment: @cale_b Yes, exactly, I’m sorry, now I’ll fix it in a question

Comment: @DavidThomas mobile responsive

Comment: So, the demo seems to be responsive on my phone, iPad and PC; does it work for you?

Comment: @DavidThomas Don`t work on android

Comment: @DavidThomas The full page is adaptable, but there is no mobile version with android

Comment: @DavidThomas I would like to have such a structure  <table><thead><tr><th></th></tr></THEAD><tr><TD>CONTENT</TD></TR></TABLE>

Comment: @DavidThomas Plugin DataTables for this

Comment: @DavidThomas Look here https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/